# RewriteRule wordpress helicon isapi filter 3

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, permalinks, helicontech

I am trying to achieve a very simple yet complicated thing:
Remove index.php from my blog URL

I have permalink setup as:
**/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/**

I have tried atleast 20 examples online in my .htaccess file but none of them work: Either the whole website doesnt work or the entries dont. I get 404s

Few examples I tried:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

and

```
Options +Followsymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

etc etc.. 
Unfortunately none of them works. Helicon tech support is asking for money to help me so doors are closed there.

Any rewrite rule expert? Will be grateful to you.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I am using IIS 6, Win2k3, Wishlist member and the permalink %postname%.

This config file for isapi rewrite by helicon, is the only one that works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Yaroslav you are my hero.

Answer (score 0):

This is a config that works for us

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

If it does not work for you, there could be hundred of reasons, starting form insufficient permissions and ending with custom IIS configuration, etc.

Try to follow Troubleshooting section of documentation, try to start from enable logging and test some basic rewrites.